# css: align justify, but text on left side

Tags: css

why doesn't `justify` work? Text stays left-aligned.

```
<div class="menu">
    text text text
</div>
.menu{
     width: 150px;
     background-color: #c1c1c1;
     color: #000;
     text-align: justify;   
}
```

Live sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/FUkpR/

Comment: It justifies just fine in Safari 5.

Comment: Though you need more then 1 line of text to see justification, which your fiddle doesn't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-align: justify` doesn't justify the last line of a text block/paragraph.

Example with longer text: http://jsfiddle.net/FUkpR/1/